# Roslyn ошибка сборки System.Runtime

Tags: c#, компиляция, roslyn

Коллеги, добрый день!

Использую Roslyn для динамического выполнения кода на C#. Возникает ошибка, пройти её не могу никак. Подскажите, если сможете.

Опишу последовательно, как воспроизводится ошибка:

Создаю проект - библиотека, framework 4.7. 
Устанавливаю зависимости через NuGet на Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting 2.0.0. Подтягивается куча зависимостей, в том числе **System.Runtime 4.3.0**. 
В библиотеке создаю класс с методом, который делает следующее: CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(expression, _options);

При вызове этого метода вылетает ошибка:
**Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.**.

Увидел, что при установке зависимостей в библиотеке в app.config для System.Runtime ставится:
bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.1.1.0"

Поправил на 4.3.0 - не помогло.

Comment: GAC пробовали почистить? *thinking* Я бы попробовал почистить gac и установленные пакеты и установить пакеты заново

Comment: Как один из вариантов: поставьте .net framework 4.7.2 + и включите automatic binding redirection в настройках проекта. А из app.config и web.config удалите эти редиректы, если есть.